# Can we get more specific flag reasons than "not an answer"?

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderation

The one thing I dislike about "not an answer" is that the flag doesn't say what the post in the answer area *is.* Is it supposed to be a new question? Is it supposed to be a comment? a comment on what post? is it just a "+1"?

The flagger already did the work to determine what the post *is* in order to determine that an answer is what the post *is not.* It wouldn't help for flaggers to specify additional information in a custom flags, because:

- Those flags occasionally survive the problem
- Those flags don't collate properly
- Those flags can't be used by the system, in a second time, to automate moderation (if 5 10k flaggers say the X post should be a comment on the Y answer, then they might probably be right and at the very least a moderator might be able to greenlight that in one click.)

Can we get more detailed "not an answer" flags?

Comment: Related: [Proposed improvement to flagging, for answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110404/proposed-improvement-to-flagging-for-answers)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I would close as a dupe if it wasn't a feature request from 2011...

Comment: :) That's why I didn't flag as a dupe. I'd think that'd make life a bit easier, instead of having this overlap sometimes between VLQ and NAA.